# How to connect the dots with arrows from left to right?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I connect the dots with arrows (from left to right) in the following plot without hardcoding the arrows?

```
library(ggplot2)

points = data.frame(x = c(0, 25, 50),
                    y = 50)

ggplot(points, aes(x, y)) +
        geom_point()
```

[image]

I could hardcode the arrow as follows:

```
arrows = data.frame(x = c(points$x[1], points$x[2]),
                    xend = c(points$x[2] - 0.5, points$x[3] - 0.5),
                    y = points$y[1],
                    yend = points$y[1])

ggplot(points, aes(x, y)) +
        geom_point(size = 4) +
        geom_segment(data = arrows, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend),
                     arrow =arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm")))
```

[image]

But, as I have many points to connect, I am looking for a more efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would `ggh4x::geom_pointpath` which also allows to add some padding between points and the path:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

points <- data.frame(
  x = c(0, 25, 50),
  y = 50
)

ggplot(points, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_pointpath(arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm")))
```

[image]

The amount of padding can be controlled via the `mult` argument:

```r
ggplot(points, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_pointpath(
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm")),
    mult = 0
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are pretty close. I actually used your code and built upon it. Hopefully this helps

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Made my own df to experiment with more points
points = data.frame(x = seq(0, 50, by = 5),
                    y = 50)

segments = points %>%
  mutate(xend = lead(x),
         yend = lead(y)) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  select(x, y, xend, yend)

ggplot(points, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  geom_segment(data = segments, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, 'cm')))
```

[image: Multiple connecting lines]